# Question about motivation for upgrading varieties to schemes (nilpotency)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-varieties

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)) on schemes where we give a motivation of nilpotence for transitioning from varieties to schemes, it says that the ring of regular functions (i.e. coordinate ring) of the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ defined by $x^2=0$ (as a variety just $V(x^2)=\{0\}$) is $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$. But if I were to use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, I'd get
$$ I(V(x^2)) = \sqrt{(x^2)} = (x) \implies \mathcal{O}_{V(x^2)}(V(x^2)) \cong \mathbb{C}[V(x^2)] = \mathbb{C}[x]/I(V(x^2))=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{C} $$
where $\mathbb{C}[V(x^2)]$ is the coordinate ring of our variety.

On the other hand, if we start by defining the *scheme* rather than the variety, which I think would be defined by writing $R= \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ and then saying that the scheme is $\text{Spec}(R)$, then the ring of regular functions (coordinate ring from previous paragraph) will be
$$ \mathbb{C}[\text{Spec}(R)] = \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)}(\text{Spec}(R)) \cong R \ncong \mathbb{C}. $$

My question is: is the moral of the story here that $(\text{Spec}(R), \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)})$ as a *pair* remembers more information (e.g. about nilpotency) than the pair $(V(I), \mathcal{O}_{V(I)})$? I'm a bit confused because I've given my *variety* a structure sheaf, and a scheme is roughly a space with a structure sheaf, but on the other hand I'm describing my "space" algebraically via prime ideals (taking Spec) along with a structure sheaf on that, and this seems to remember more information. Is it the fact that before you even look at the structure sheaf of the variety, it has already forgotten all of the nilpotency information, i.e.
$$ \{0\} =  V(x) = V(x^2) = V(x^3) = \cdots $$
so when you take the structure sheaves of $V(x^n)$, they'll all be the same because the nilpotency information has already been forgotten?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: is the moral of the story here that $(\text{Spec}(R), \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)})$ as a *pair* remembers more information (e.g. about nilpotency) than the pair $(V(I), \mathcal{O}_{V(I)})$?

Exactly. Let's take a look at the examples you consider $R_n=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$. Prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\subset R_n$ are in one-to-one correspondence with prime ideals $(x^n)\subseteq\mathfrak{P}\subset\mathbb{C}[x]$. Now, any such $\mathfrak{P}$ is prime so that $(x^n)\subset\mathfrak{P}$ implies $(x)\subseteq \mathfrak{P}$. Conversely, if $(x)\subseteq\mathfrak{P}$ we clearly have $(x^n)\subset\mathfrak{P}$.

What does this mean? We just exhibited a homeomorphism between the underlying topological spaces $Spec(R_n)$ and $Spec(R_1)$ - I just presented the bijection as sets, you can verify that everything is continuous.

On the other hand, as you already noted, the structure sheaves of both schemes are different.

To conclude let me just mention that it's always possible to endow a closed subset of a scheme with its "reduced subscheme structure". This process is basically taking the radical as you do at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for (in particular the bijection between the Spec's)! One quick question: did you by any chance mean to write $\mathfrak{p}\subset R_n$ instead of $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ in your third sentence, or rather, what is your $R$?

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit it later since I have to leave now. The idea is that for any $n> 1$ you have a homeomorphism with $R_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have just thought to ask this, presumably this bijection still works if you replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @mathphys yes, just keep in mind that in that case $(x)$ is no longer a maximal ideal.