# Going from varieties to schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, affine-varieties, zariski-topology

I've been studying the Nullstellensatz and the Zariski topology.

I understand the basic gist is that in $\Bbb C[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$, varieties are in one-to-one correspondence with radical ideals. Each of these is in turn in a one-to-one correspondence with the set of prime ideals supersetting it. So, the (original) Zariski topology directly on $\Bbb C^n$ translates to the (modern) Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(\Bbb C[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n])$.

I also get that the next step is to look at the topology on $\text{Spec}(R)$ directly for some arbitrary commutative ring $R$. The "varieties" of the ring are again given by the radical ideals, the (non-generic) "points" are the maximal ideals, etc.

Schemes, then, are often described as representing varieties "with multiplicity," so that in $\Bbb C[x]$, $((x-1)^2)$ generates a different scheme than $(x-1)$. But, my perspective has been that varieties map to radical ideals map to sets of prime ideals in the spectrum. I can get that schemes are arbitrary ideals, rather than radical ideals, but what do *they* map to in the spectrum? The set of prime ideals containing $((x-1)^2)$ is exactly the same as $(x-1)$, so how are these represented as different schemes in the spectrum?

Basically: how are schemes represented in the spectrum? Are they also closed under the Zariski topology?

Comment: Non-reduced schemes have the same underlying set and topology as their associated reduced scheme. The difference is the rings of functions. In your example, you get different coordinate rings, namely $\mathbb C[x]/(x-1) \cong \mathbb C$ which is spanned over $\mathbb C$ by $1$, versus $\mathbb C[x]/(x-1)^2 \cong \mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$, which is spanned by $1$ and $x$. The point is that if you restrict a regular function $f$ to the former scheme, you just get the value $f(1)$. If you restrict a regular function to the latter, you get $f(1) + f'(1)(x-1)$, the 1st order Taylor polynomial...

Comment: ....This has various geometric consequences. If we stick our point-on-a-line inside a plane, instead of a pencil of lines through the point there is now just one line through the "double point," namely the line we started with that prescribed the tangent direction at the double point.

Comment: Thanks - I understand that they would have different coordinate rings. How is this reflected in the underlying setup? The two schemes are the same set of prime ideals and look the same in the Zariski topology. Do they look different in the structure sheaf?

Comment: Exactly, and you've said yourself why, because the structure sheaf is just the coordinate ring and all of its localizations conveniently packaged together into a single object. For example, for an affine variety the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf is canonically isomorphic to the classical coordinate ring.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I guess the only thing I'm trying to get is, for any scheme, are the subschemes of that scheme somehow represented within the scheme? The subvarieties certainly are, as Zariski-closed sets of prime ideals. Multiple subschemes would correspond to the same Zariski-closed sets, and I think the structure sheaf (for the parent scheme) would also associate the same localization ring to them. It isn't unless you make a brand new scheme with the subscheme, with its own spectrum and etc, that you can see that it is different than its reduced version. Is that the right view?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is what you're getting at, but I'll give it a go: closed subschemes $Z$ of a scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ are in bijection with quotients $\mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_Z \to 0$. Once you have a quotient, you can take its kernel to obtain the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_Z$ cutting out $Z$. The underlying topological space can then be computed, let's say on an affine chart $U$, by checking which prime ideals of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ contain $\mathcal I_Z(U)$...

Comment: ...If you, for example, take the square of $\mathcal I_Z$, you will in general get a quotient sheaf which is distinct from $\mathcal O_Z$ but has the same underlying topological (sub)space as $Z \subset X$. Does all of this clear up your confusion?

Comment: OK, yes, I think I get a little of it. Do you have any reading references that would be good for someone at my level with this material? Thank you

Comment: Vakil's notes are comprehensive and begin with a couple of rough chapters on categories and sheaves, but if you just start reading at Chapter 3, dipping back into 1 & 2 as needed, I don't think the going will be too tough.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3246796/252641) may be of interest.