# Schemes and Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

Good folks!

If I may ask a relatively simple question when it comes to algebraic geometry... I was wondering if one of you people might help me in explaining in more detail an example that is in fact contained in the very opening sentence of Wikipedia's article on schemes:

> The equations $x = 0$ and $x^2 = 0$ define the same algebraic variety and different schemes.

In as far as defining the same varieties, I find that to be pretty straightforward. A variety is merely the zero locus of a set of polynomial equations, and so, since $V(x)=V(x^2)$, they define the same variety.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain in as straightforward terms as possible how they define different schemes?

Comment: The gist of it is that $k[x]/(x) \simeq k$ while $k[x]/(x^2) \simeq k \times k$.

Comment: It is really as simple as that, huh? Well, thank you, sir.

Comment: What are the local rings $A_p$ of $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $B = k[x]/(x)$ ? Are there finitely many algebra isomorphisms $\phi_j : A_{S_j} \to B_{Z_j}$ compatible with the local rings ? In $B$ there is only one prime ideal $q = \{0\}$, in $A$, $ux+v $ is a unit iff $u \ne 0$ so $p = (x)$ is the unique prime ideal and $A_p = (A-p)^{-1} A =A$ but there is no isomorphism $A=A_p \to B_q=B$ thus $A \not \cong B$.

Comment: Going to need some time to properly digest this, but cheers for giving me the right questions to think of, and the right direction to go in. I would consider this question to have been answered to my satisfaction at this point. :)

Comment: @RubenduBurck: $k[X]/\langle X^{2} \rangle$ is not isomorphic to $k \times k$ (unless you meant as $k$-vector spaces, and we really want to compare them as rings). You can see that the latter is reduced, whereas the former has nilpotents. (Also, you can see that $k \times k$ has two prime ideals, corresponding to each factor. As a scheme, $Spec(k \times k)$ is the coproduct of two copies of $Spec(k)$).

Comment: @AlexWertheim I did mean as $k$-vector spaces, but I see now that we want to compare them as rings.

Comment: I recently asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3246796/252641), you may be interested in having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there are nice answers in the comments, let me add a more philosophical answer.

As you said, varieties are just the zero sets of some polynomials and therefore cannot see multiplicities of the zeroes. But somehow the multiplicities should be taken into account as well and the notion of schemes does that. If there is a multiple zero, the point of the scheme corresponding to that zero can be visualized as being a "thicker" point and you can see that "thickness" as nilpotence in the local rings that come with a scheme. Schemes not having "thicker stuff" are called reduced and that notion is maybe also known to you for rings. A reduced ring is a ring not having non-zero nilpotent elements. As Ruben already mentioned, for your example it comes down to comparing $k[x]/(x) \cong k$ and $k[x]/(x^2)$. There you can explicitly see, that $x$ is nilpotent in the latter ring as $x^2 = 0$ in $k[x]/(x^2)$ and that is making the point thicker.

Comment: Just to clarify, since the claim also appears in this answer: $k[X]/\langle X^{2} \rangle$ is not isomorphic to $k \times k$ (unless you meant as $k$-vector spaces, and we really want to compare them as rings). See my comment above.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I changed my answer accordingly. Thanks!